# Creating mapkit's showsUserLocation pin ripple animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

Has any one successfully created user location pin that has a ripple like effect that 4.x (or higher) mapkit gives when we use `mkMakkit.showUserLoaction = YES`;

If any one has done it please guide me how to do it or past sample code that does that effect.

The user location in the mapkit is read-only property. Has anyone able to move the pin from user actual location. That is in my senario when the user location is not available for cases like iTouch user can select his location, I don't want to show user at Infinite Loop,CA but the location he prefers to choose.

Comment: let me see if i understand what you mean:
you want a pin on MKMap that you can move and save "current" pin location. right?